# W/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.http.HTTPRequest: Request failed due to a permanent error

Tags: android, mapbox, mapquest

I have created a map using this tutorial: https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/android-sdk/
It was running good since 2 months ago, now I get the error:

> W/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.http.HTTPRequest: Request failed due to a permanent error

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to change **MapQuestAccountManager** by **MapboxAccountManager** (using an API key from Mapbox webpage and not from MapQuest webpage) and not to call **setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_mr);** before **MapboxAccountManager**

```
public class MainActivityMR extends Activity {
private MapboxMap mMap;
private MapView mMapView;
private String linkid ="";
private String evento ="";
String latpass;
String lonpass;
String vod;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_mr);

    //MapQuestAccountManager.start(getApplicationContext());
    //MapboxAccountManager.start(this, getString(R.string.access_token));
    MapboxAccountManager.start(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.access_token));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_mr);
```

get your API Key from https://www.mapbox.com/studio/account/tokens/
and add this line to strings.xml

```
<string name="access_token">YOUR_API_KEY</string>
```